# How to make the items in the flexbox align in the center and to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Proposed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICcKi.jpg)

I've made a 3 column flexbox and I need all flexbox items to be in the center and the items that are in rows that are not full to be center and aligned to the left. What would you guys recommend?

I currently have the below but the bottom row is aligning in the center.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to include some markup-- this might be a bit short of a [mcve] without it.  You could try justifying the content to the start instead; or you could consider swapping this out for a CSS Grid based solution instead.

Comment: Try to play around with the styling `align-content: flex-start`. Here is a nice guide to CSS flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Using `justify-content: center;` will always put the odd flex item in the center with `flex-wrap` when resizing. I would suggest using a different way to center the `flex` container. In this case, I used `width: fit-content` with `margin: auto;` to center. You could also use a `max-width` on the flex parent. I used `space-between` to space the flex items as using a static `gap` is not as responsive.

See the notes below:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: fit-content; /* allows margin auto to center */
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  width: calc(100%/3.1); /* .1 for spacing paired with space-between for smaller screens */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%; /* responsive images */
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff">
    <h6> Hello World </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff">
    <h6> Hello World </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff">
    <h6> Hello World </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/000/fff">
    <h6> Hello World </h6>
  </div>
</div>
```